# Regex: get recursive brackets with prefixes

Tags: php, regex, string

Please, what is the correct php code, using a regex pattern, to get `$result` from `$string`?

```
$string = 'xmlns(ns=http://testurl.com/now)xpointer(//section/datePublished/text())';
preg_match($regex, $string, $result);
```

Output:

```
$result = array(
    'xmlns' => 'ns=http://testurl.com/now',
    'xpointer' => '//section/datePublished/text()'
);
```

Brackets can be recursive (as `text()`).

Comment: What do you mean by `get $result from $string`? Maybe it would be better to iterate over `result` and construct the string then do a simple `if .. ==` https://3v4l.org/0Fk5H ... oh or is the `$result` an example of what is built from the `preg_match` call?

Answer (score 0):

Use `/(\w+)\((.*?)\)(?=\w+\(|$)/` regex pattern that match any string before parentheses and string in `()` after it.

```
preg_match_all("/(\w+)\((.*?)\)(?=\w+\(|$)/", $string, $m);
$result = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/6OR1i)

Comment: Thank you Mohammad. This regex pattern answers the question correctly.