# What's the RegEx pattern to get recursive bracket with specific prefix?

Tags: php, regex, xinclude

Please, what is the correct php code, using a regex pattern, to get `$output` from `$string`?

```
$string = 'xmlns(ns=http://testurl.com/now)xpointer(//section/datePublished/text())';
```

Generalizing:

```
$string = 'string1(string1_1)string2(string2_1)';
```

Brackets can be recursive (as `text()`).
i.e. `string1_1` and/or `string2_1` may contain other brackets.
    $string = 'string1(string1_1())string2(string2_1()string2_2());

Knowing the brackets prefix `xmlns`, I need the regex pattern to get `//section/datePublished/text()`, i.e. knowing `string1`I need the regex pattern to get `string1_1` (or `string1_1()`).

Knowing the brackets prefix `xpointer`, I need the regex pattern to get `ns=http://testurl.com/now`, i.e. knowing `string2`I need the regex pattern to get `string2_1` (or `string2_1()string2_2(`).

Can you explain the process?

Comment: Your strategy depends on what you know about the rest of the string. I. e. can you rely on framing portions like `xpointer(` and `xmlns(`?

Comment: You have contradicting pattern in your string that you want to capture. One parenthesis case is, where non-greedy capturing is needed and in other greedy. So a general solution is not possible. We will need more samples to exploit something that can make it work. Like if string starts with alphabet vs string starting with double slash in the parenthesis

Comment: I think this is like your [before question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53560739/5104748)

Comment: I think it's different, because the intent and the results are different. My first question asks about getting both prefix and the text inside the brackets, without knowing them. My second question asks about getting the text inside the brackets after a known prefix (xpointer or xmlns).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: get recursive brackets with prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560739/regex-get-recursive-brackets-with-prefixes)

Answer (score 0):

This can help

```
preg_match('/xmlns\((.*)\)xpointer\((.*)\)/', $inString, $outArray);
$output = $outArray[2];
$output1 = $outArray[1];
```

demo: https://www.phpregexonline.com/q/4